# Geometry node difference gives inconsistent results

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a dice with the symbols on the face carved out.
To do so I setup some geometry nodes to extrude a string and set it on the face normal. Then I thought a difference between the cube and the extruded face would give me what I want.
[image]
However I get the following results, two faces have the symbol as desired, all the others are flat. To add to my confusion the faces showing the symbols and the blank ones are different depending on the string used.
[image]

When viewing in wireframe mode all the symbols are where they're supposed to be. They just seem to not get caught in the difference operation for some reason. I've tried translating them a bit so the edges would be proturding out of the dice face, thinking maybe they were just under the face but it does not change anything.
[image]

So... What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue** - you Extrude to negative value, that generates mesh with switched normal orientation for your boolean operation. This also generates even more random errors for shapes with hole (like 0, 8, 9, ...).

[image]

---

**Solution** - add **Flip Face** node after *Fill Curve* node and Extrude in positive direction.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notes:

- You can extrude in negative too, just move *Flip Face* node after *Extrude Mesh* node instead. There is no difference.
- For shapes with hole like (0, 6, 8 ,9 ...) disable *Individual* under *Extrude* node to prevent extruding connections with a hole.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I upvoted but I don't have enough reputation for it to show yet... I observed these problems with the holes too. Is it because this way of setting up the geometry nodes is bad and I should do it differently? Or is it a "bug"?

Comment: Negative Extrude generates normals in unwanted orientation for boolean operation. When extruded in positive, non-manifold issue was solved as well ... answer edited :)

Comment: It works pretty nice, one minor trouble is that by doing this way the numbers are mirrored, works for 0 but not for the others (unless I want to give a cool effect to the dice lol). Every rotation I tried so far brought the previous issue back so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Solution is even more simple ... :) Sorry for that I spotted later, that. See edit. Also you can use negative Extrude, just place Flip Face after Extrusion node instead :)